# How to replace N-number of matches in the string?

Tags: java, groovy

So, how to do that in groovy (or java)? I look for something like this:

```
someString.replaceN(/(?<=\p{L}) (?=\p{L})/, '', 3) // replace first 3 matches
```

For now, I only came to this stupid solution:

```
(0..2).each { s = s.replaceFirst(/(?<=\p{L}) (?=\p{L})/, '') }
```

---

In other languages it's easy as pie:

- Python - [subn(count=3)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn)
- PHP - [preg_replace(limit=3)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- Rust - [Regex.replacen](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replacen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are after is

```
3.times { s = s.replaceFirst(/(?<=\p{L}) (?=\p{L})/, '') }
```

Or if you need it more often you can also easily add the method to String class like

```
String.metaClass.replace << { pattern, replacement, n ->
    def result = delegate
    n.times { result = result.replaceFirst pattern, replacement }
    result
}

someString.replace(/(?<=\p{L}) (?=\p{L})/, '', 3)
```